# IC overheating in Inverter circuit

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am building this DC to AC inverter circuit as shown in the below diagram.[image: IC555 Inverter Circuit]

I am using 3.3k ohm,2W resistors in place of all 3k ohm,2W resistors in the circuit diargam due to availability issues. I replaced the transistor 2SC4029 by power MOSFET IRF3205 and the capacitor rating is 40V .

The input 12V DC is given by a 12V,1A adapter. I checked the iput voltage before plugging it in but as soon as I connect the wires, the input voltage drops to 2.5V and the IC heats with burning smell coming out from it.

I checked all the connections, everything seems to be connected correctly. I have not yet connected the transformer in the circuit.

Please try to explain me what is going wrong. If any more specifications are needed, I would like to know about that.

Thank you.

Comment: For a start, you've probably used up your 555. When you say you have not connected the transformer yet, what have you connected?

Comment: After burning smell, the part is no good anymore.

Comment: Yes, I did use up my first IC. When I said I haven't connected the transformer yet, I meant that I have not connected anything at the output (there is no current drawing device connected to the output.) I replaced the IC but still the same thing is happening. @uint128_t

Comment: Are you sure the timer you are using can withstand 12V? Can you try a lower voltage?

Comment: How will you reset the transformer? Where will you free wheel the magnitizing current?

Comment: The fact that you found this circuit somewhere online does not mean that its a good design. An 1N4007 is a weird choice, no flyback diode, single ended drive, to name just three.

Answer (score 1):

> I have not yet connected the transformer in the circuit.

Here's the first problem - circuits like this need a load connected or the transformer will rapidly become saturated and take a lot of current. It seems you are operating the 555 at a fixed duty cycle and each time the transistor switches on you are accumulating energy into the core - this needs to be released into the load. No load connected means the energy gets turned into a voltage spike on the primary and this will usually destroy the transistor and then destroy the device that drives the transistor.

Unfortunately, this is what I think is happening to your devices.

Comment: So what should I do, connect the transformer in the circuit and then try testing again or this circuit is too faulty. I should look for a new one ? @Andy aka

Comment: Put a proper load on it but it's not a great circuit but, it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its just my college electronics project. I just need to test the output, thats all. I will try connecting the load and testing. Thanks for the help. @Andy aka